# Regex Question with questionmark quantifier don't work

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a problem with the ?-quantifier:
Base is this string to check: 'section1,section2,section3'
Sometimes section1 is not there, so i have only 'section2,section3'
I have to analyse only the section2 and section3.

So i tried this regular expression:

```
'~,?(.*),(.*)~Ui'
```

But this dosn't work.

I know, that I can work with explode (,) and count the values... But this workaround is not possible.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you give examples of strings that must match, and strings that must not ?

Comment: Use `'~([^,]+),([^,]+)$~'`

Comment: What about `~(?:(.*),)?(.*),(.*)$~` ?

Comment: Yes, the part with [^,]+ solved my problem. Thank you Wiktor

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
'~([^,]+),([^,]+)$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LXgAh8/1).

**Details**

- `([^,]+)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than a comma
- `,` - a comma
- `([^,]+)` - Capturing group 2: any one or more chars other than a comma
- `$` - end of string.